# React router, props gone after page reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Been stuck with this for a time now, and I'm not really able to find an answer or work my mind around it..
So, I got a main component, serving my other components with a prop called subjects.

```
App.js
--------------------------------
getSubjects() {
    if(Auth.isUserAuthenticated()) {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Authorization', `bearer ${Auth.getToken()}`);
        let fetchInit = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers
        };

        return (
            fetch('api/subjects', fetchInit)
                .then(this.getJSON)
                .then((data) => {
                    this.setState({
                        subjects: data.doc
                    });
                })
        )
    }
}

<Route path='/editsubject/:id' render={(props) => <EditSubject {...props} 
subjects={this.state.subjects}/>

Edit.js
---------------------------------
componentWillMount() {
    let paramId = this.props.match.params.id;
    let isSubjectItem = this.props.subjects.filter((sub) => {
        return sub._id === paramId;
    })[0];
    this.setState({subject: isSubjectItem});
}
```

All of this works fine, and I can use my subject through the state in the Edit component.
All tho, whenever I try to reload/refresh the page, the app crashes. The props.subjects gets undefined. I'm guessing the part where App.js sends Edit the props never invokes when the page reload in Edit component.

The localStorage routine has crossed my mind, but I would rather avoid it, hoping that it's just some crucial part I'm missing about how to work with react...

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: When you refresh the page, all the component state and props will be gone. You need to put some condition like if `typeof this.props.subjects !== 'undefined'` then only proceed otherwise show some kind of loader or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, when you refresh the page and get straight to the router editsubject, there's a chance that subjects is undefined (not loaded yet byt getSubjects). I don't know where you call the getSubjects method, but maybe in the App constructor or componentDidMount is the best place.

And to solve the undefined problem, you should use a defaultProps. Like this:

```
Edit.defaultProps = {
  subjects: [],
};
```

this way you don't need to make a if condition too see if there is data in the subjects, and when the method in component father loads the subjects, everything is gonna work ok.